# displaying search query results in all pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I've made an image search application using unsplash api. The app contains pagination and that's where the problem lies. When I search for something like, say flower, then it shows flowers in the first page but when I go to second page then there aren't flowers anymore but default photos which is generated by the fetchPhotos function in componentDidMount because of re-render I believe. Is there a way through which I can view the search query results in all the pages until I refresh the page?

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-napier-6lzfs?file=/src/Pagination.js:0-2694)

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Pagination from "./Pagination";
import List from "./List";
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

const LOAD_STATE = {
  SUCCESS: "SUCCESS",
  ERROR: "ERROR",
  LOADING: "LOADING"
};

const appId = "N1ZIgf1m1v9gZJhledpAOTXqS8HqL2DuiEyXZI9Uhsk";
const BASE_URL = "https://api.unsplash.com/photos?page=1";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      photos: [],
      totalPhotos: 0,
      perPage: 5,
      currentPage: 1,
      loadState: LOAD_STATE.LOADING,
      search: ""
    };
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    const { search, perPage } = this.state;
    console.log(search);
    const url =
      "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=1&query=" +
      search +
      "&client_id=" +
      appId;

    const options = {
      params: {
        client_id: appId,
        page: 1,
        per_page: perPage,
        order_by: "popularity"
      }
    };

    this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.LOADING });
    axios
      .get(url, options)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(typeof response.data);
        let photos;
        try {
          photos = response.data.results;
        } catch {
          photos = [];
        }
        this.setState({
          photos,
          totalPhotos: parseInt(response.headers["x-total"]),
          currentPage: 1,
          loadState: LOAD_STATE.SUCCESS
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.ERROR });
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchPhotos(this.state.currentPage);
  }

  fetchPhotos(page) {
    var self = this;
    const { perPage } = this.state;

    const options = {
      params: {
        client_id: appId,
        page: page,
        per_page: perPage,
        order_by: "popularity"
      }
    };

    this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.LOADING });
    axios
      .get(BASE_URL, options)
      .then(response => {
        self.setState({
          photos: response.data,
          totalPhotos: parseInt(response.headers["x-total"]),
          currentPage: page,
          loadState: LOAD_STATE.SUCCESS
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.ERROR });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <input
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          type="text"
          name="search"
          placeholder="Enter query"
        />
        <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="button">
          Submit
        </button>
        <Pagination
          current={this.state.currentPage}
          total={this.state.totalPhotos}
          perPage={this.state.perPage}
          onPageChanged={this.fetchPhotos.bind(this)}
        />
        {this.state.loadState === LOAD_STATE.LOADING ? (
          <div className="loader" />
        ) : (
          <List data={this.state.photos} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Pagination

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Pagination extends Component {
  pages() {
    var pages = [];
    for (var i = this.rangeStart(); i <= this.rangeEnd(); i++) {
      pages.push(i);
    }
    return pages;
  }

  rangeStart() {
    var start = this.props.current - this.props.pageRange;
    return start > 0 ? start : 1;
  }

  rangeEnd() {
    var end = this.props.current + this.props.pageRange;
    var totalPages = this.totalPages();
    return end < totalPages ? end : totalPages;
  }

  totalPages() {
    return Math.ceil(this.props.total / this.props.perPage);
  }

  nextPage() {
    return this.props.current + 1;
  }

  prevPage() {
    return this.props.current - 1;
  }

  hasFirst() {
    return this.rangeStart() !== 1;
  }

  hasLast() {
    return this.rangeEnd() < this.totalPages();
  }

  hasPrev() {
    return this.props.current > 1;
  }

  hasNext() {
    return this.props.current < this.totalPages();
  }

  changePage(page) {
    this.props.onPageChanged(page);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="pagination">
        <div className="pagination__left">
          <a
            href="#"
            className={!this.hasPrev() ? "hidden" : ""}
            onClick={e => this.changePage(this.prevPage())}
          >
            Prev
          </a>
        </div>

        <div className="pagination__mid">
          <ul>
            <li className={!this.hasFirst() ? "hidden" : ""}>
              <a href="#" onClick={e => this.changePage(1)}>
                1
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className={!this.hasFirst() ? "hidden" : ""}>...</li>
            {this.pages().map((page, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index}>
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    onClick={e => this.changePage(page)}
                    className={this.props.current == page ? "current" : ""}
                  >
                    {page}
                  </a>
                </li>
              );
            })}
            <li className={!this.hasLast() ? "hidden" : ""}>...</li>
            <li className={!this.hasLast() ? "hidden" : ""}>
              <a href="#" onClick={e => this.changePage(this.totalPages())}>
                {this.totalPages()}
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div className="pagination__right">
          <a
            href="#"
            className={!this.hasNext() ? "hidden" : ""}
            onClick={e => this.changePage(this.nextPage())}
          >
            Next
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Pagination.defaultProps = {
  pageRange: 2
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

`onPageChanged={this.fetchPhotos.bind(this)}`

because `fetchPhotos` doesn't use any sort of query to fetch a specific sort of photo, so when the page changes you get the default response.

You currently have two functions for fetching photos that are working differently. You need to refactor your code to a single photo-fetching function that uses the current `query` from the state.

**Update**

Something like this:

```
fetchPhotos(page=1) {
    var self = this;
    const { search, perPage } = this.state;
    const url = `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=${page}&client_id=${appId}`
    const url = search ? `${url}&query=search` : url

    const options = {
      params: {
        client_id: appId,
        page: page,
        per_page: perPage,
        order_by: "popularity"
      }
    };

    this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.LOADING });
    axios
      .get(url, options)
      .then(response => {
        self.setState({
          photos: response.data,
          totalPhotos: parseInt(response.headers["x-total"]),
          currentPage: page,
          loadState: LOAD_STATE.SUCCESS
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.ERROR });
      });
  }
```

Then you can call `fetchPhotos` on mount and also use it instead of your `onSubmit`, which it looks like you can get rid of.

```
<button type="submit" onClick={this.fetchPhotos} className="button">
          Submit
        </button>
```

Comment: but the apis are different, how do I make a single photo fetching function? can you show me? i'm still a new developer

Comment: I'm still getting some error here. can you see once https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-http-0ulby?file=/src/App.js .. the setState for search result is different so I created one conditional expression there too but I think I'm missing something there

Comment: I'm almost there. but when I search something like cycle, then all the page numbers are displayed in the first page without prev and next button. but when I go to second page, then the prev and next buttons are shown.. can you please help me with that?

Comment: so using .bind for fetchPhotos is creating a problem (if you look at the requests being fired). Easiest fix is to use an arrow function: `fetchPhotos = (page = 1) => { ... }` and then just hook it up directly. So `onPageChanged={this.fetchPhotos.bind(this)}` would just become  `onPageChanged={this.fetchPhotos}`

Answer (score 0):

Your `onPageChanged` is given a function that fetches default photos. The only function you have that fetches photos based on dynamic input/state is in your `handleSubmit`. Extract the body of `handleSubmit` into an arrow function in another variable and call this new extracted function in `handleSubmit` at the same time pass this new function to `onPageChanged` prop.
Leaving you with the same API calls in `handleSubmit` and `onPageChanged`

Since you are using a class component, extracting the body of `handleSubmit` into a constant may not be a good idea.

Instead rename your `fetchPhotos` method to `fetchDefaultPhotos` and your `handleSubmit` method to `fetchPhotos` to better represent what each method does.

Pass the newly renamed `fetchPhotos` to `onPageChanged` and call `fetchDefaultPhotos` in your `componentDidMount`. You may also create a new `handleSubmit` method that only makes a call to `fetchPhotos`, if still needed.

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      photos: [],
      totalPhotos: 0,
      perPage: 5,
      currentPage: 1,
      loadState: LOAD_STATE.LOADING,
      search: ""
    };
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(newPage) {
    this.fetchPhotos(newPage)
  }

  fetchPhotos(newPage) {
    const { search, perPage } = this.state;
    console.log(search);
    const url =
      "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=1&query=" +
      search +
      "&client_id=" +
      appId;

    const options = {
      params: {
        client_id: appId,
        page: 1,
        per_page: perPage,
        order_by: "popularity"
      }
    };

    this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.LOADING });
    axios
      .get(url, options)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(typeof response.data);
        let photos;
        try {
          photos = response.data.results;
        } catch {
          photos = [];
        }
        this.setState({
          photos,
          totalPhotos: parseInt(response.headers["x-total"]),
          currentPage: newPage,
          loadState: LOAD_STATE.SUCCESS
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.ERROR });
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchDefaultPhotos(this.state.currentPage);
  }

  fetchDefaultPhotos(page) {
    var self = this;
    const { perPage } = this.state;

    const options = {
      params: {
        client_id: appId,
        page: page,
        per_page: perPage,
        order_by: "popularity"
      }
    };

    this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.LOADING });
    axios
      .get(BASE_URL, options)
      .then(response => {
        self.setState({
          photos: response.data,
          totalPhotos: parseInt(response.headers["x-total"]),
          currentPage: page,
          loadState: LOAD_STATE.SUCCESS
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({ loadState: LOAD_STATE.ERROR });
      });
  }
}
```

**Update**:

Here is a working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-op-sbx-6rnhu

Comment: you mean to say, do something like `const handleSubmit=function(){.....}` and then use it later in onPageChanged={fetchPhotos, handleSubmit}??

Comment: I've changed my sandbox. now it's almost working except for one part. whenever I search for something, all the page numbers are shown in the first page itself without the prev and next button. but if I click on page number 2 then I can see the prev and next button and most of the middle pages be shown as `....` is there a way to fix it? https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-http-0ulby?file=/sandbox.config.json

Comment: Your `this.setState` in the `handleSubmit` now renamed to `fetchOptions` is hardcoded to always set `currentPage` to `1`. You should change that and use the argument passed to the method instead.

Comment: it's set to page though. I didn't see 1 in setState

Comment: Your initial `handleSubmit` which I renamed to `fetchPhotos` is hard-coded to `1` it's the initial `fetchPhotos` now renamed to `fetchDefaultPhotos` that is set to page. Check properly

Comment: no check my sandbox. I did it with one function itself https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-http-0ulby?file=/src/ListItem.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218756/discussion-between-calebpitan-and-gonnabefireifnohelp).